# 'This PC is ready for Windows 11' but not getting the update

Tags: windows, windows-update, windows-11

From the last week the 'Windows Update' section is showing the following:
This PC is ready for Windows 11

[image]
Also, checked the system requirements using 'PC Health Check'.

What is the reason I am not getting the update?
My friend has the same machine, and he's got it.

Thank you

Comment: I mean, it literally says "Specific timing for when it will be offered can vary as we get it ready for you.", i.e. your PC meets the requirements, but you don't get the option to update yet. Are you looking for specific details about why, or what?

Comment: @Luaan To be fair, I'm both a techie and a native English speaker, and that language takes some effort to figure out.

Comment: @Luaan why.....

Comment: to me it is even weirder, a colleague has same model pc, he received the update; some time after that i received it too, but first i had to reboot because of another update, and when i returned to windows update the windows 11 update was not there anymore; it's been months since then

Answer (score 12, accepted):

It depends on the PC, EVEN if the computer is exactly same, it depends. The windows update is preparing update for your PC. Then after sometime, It will appear as a optional update. Waiting is recommended, BUT if you want to upgrade now, use this app: [Windows 11 Installation Assistant](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/software-download/windows11). To use it scroll down and select *Download Now* under *Windows 11 Installation Assistant*. It will guide you to install Windows 11.

Comment: "windows update is preparing update for your PC" is a bunch of meaningless fluff.

Comment: Although well-meaning, this answer is basically wrong. There is no update being "prepared" for this PC specifically, there is a team at Microsoft deciding how quickly to roll out the new version, and how confident they are that it will be bug-free on different hardware. That's actually important to know before upgrading manually, because by doing so you are taking the risk that there _are_ bugs with some of your hardware, which Microsoft would have fixed before offering you the automatic upgrade.

Answer (score 12):

Microsoft is rolling out big updates slowly, so that servers are not overloaded and if any bugs are caught, not everyone is affected.

Answer (score 7):

The Windows blog have [more details](https://blogs.windows.com/windowsexperience/2021/08/31/windows-11-available-on-october-5/)

> new eligible devices will be offered the upgrade first. The upgrade will then roll out over time to in-market devices based on intelligence models that consider hardware eligibility, reliability metrics, age of device and other factors that impact the upgrade experience. We expect all eligible devices to be offered the free upgrade to Windows 11 by mid-2022)

That is, your device meets the minimum requirements and should get the upgrade offer somewhere between now and mid-2022. However, Microsoft deliberately only pushes to the hardware they've actually tested and verified to work, then slowly expands to other similar models or perhaps those they proactively acquire and test. In the meantime, they will also release updates to fix the bugs they found.

This way they minimized the "Windows upgrade broke my PC" incidents from untested hardware combination, but you can skip the queue and install it right away with the [assistant](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/software-download/windows11), taking the risk that your hardware turns out to be the problematic ones. The problems you encounter (if any) would then be fixed by a later update, and once everything works, PCs similar to yours will get their offer.

Answer (score 1):

you might need to clean Windows updates and caches.

1. Right click on Windows drive > click properties
2. click disk clean up
3. click "Clean up system files"
4. select all the windows related cache and select delivery optimization files
5. click ok

It will some time after all is finished, restart the pc and then search for update.

Answer (score 0):

Last comments are from November. Server shouldn't be all that busy now, yet I have the same issue since January.

**Great news—your PC meets the minimum system requirements for Windows 11. Specific timing for when it will be offered can vary as we get it ready for you.**

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](https://superuser.com/questions/ask). To get notified when this question gets new answers, you can [follow this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/345661). Once you have enough [reputation](https://superuser.com/help/whats-reputation), you can also [add a bounty](https://superuser.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/1129702)

Comment: you may try using Windows 11 Installation Assistant. That's how I upgraded to Windows 11 ). https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/software-download/windows11

Answer (score 0):

Yesterday I switched the bios switch setting on for AMD MB so it would be eligible to upgrade to win11. After that, the downloadable tool said your pc is ready for win11 but the windows update screen still said no. And today the update screen was "your PC is ready for win11 but specific timing etc.. ". So I just did a restart and after that it popped the win11 update on my screen.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).